# HomeKit didFindNewAccessory delegate method not working, why?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, homekit

i am using xcode 7 beta 4, HomeKit Accessory simulator version 1.3.

i have enabled HomeKit capability for project, added entitlement of homekit with provisioning profile. with same provisioning profile and entitlement it's working fine in my another project but not with my current project.

my code is

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,HMAccessoryBrowserDelegate {


    let accessoryBrowser = HMAccessoryBrowser()
    let homeManager = HMHomeManager()
    var accessories: [HMAccessory] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        accessoryBrowser.delegate = self
        accessoryBrowser.startSearchingForNewAccessories()

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    func accessoryBrowser(browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didFindNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
        if !localAccessoriesContains(accessory) {
            accessories.append(accessory);
            tableView.reloadData()
            NSLog("new accessory found")


        }
    }

    func accessoryBrowser(browser: HMAccessoryBrowser, didRemoveNewAccessory accessory: HMAccessory) {
        removeFromLocalAccessories(accessory)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```